# Referencing FROM subquery alias inside CASE from UPDATE SET

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me understand why this operation

```sql
UPDATE
    [Case_11268].[dbo].[Annotations]
SET
    [usercreated_id] = CASE 
        WHEN 
             EXISTS (SELECT id from gu where anno.[usercreated_id] = gu.id)
        THEN 
            'SOMEVALUE'
        ELSE 
            [usercreated_id] 
        END
FROM (
    SELECT 
        agu.userid, us.id 
    FROM
        [Case_11268].[dbo].[Annotations] anno
    INNER JOIN 
        [TSI_Main].[dbo].aspnet_Users us
    INNER JOIN 
        [TSI_Main].[dbo].aspnet_Membership mem on us.userid = mem.userid
    INNER JOIN
        [TSI_Main].[dbo].AdminGroupUsers agu on mem.userid = agu.userid
    INNER JOIN
        [TSI_Main].[dbo].AdminGroups ag on agu.adminGroup = ag.id
    WHERE
        ag.[deleted] = 0
    GROUP BY agu.userid, us.id
) AS gu
```

Throws this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Invalid object name 'gu'.

Comment: Can you explain, in plain English, exactly what you are trying to do? I'm having a hard time parsing your query.

Comment: Simple answer: the table aliases created in a `FROM` clause are not re-usable in other FROM clauses.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RBarryYoung!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's almost certainly a much simpler way of writing this. Possibly

```
UPDATE [Case_11268].[dbo].[Annotations]
SET    [usercreated_id] = 'SOMEVALUE'
WHERE  [usercreated_id] IN (SELECT us.id
                            FROM   [TSI_Main].[dbo].aspnet_Users us
                                   INNER JOIN [TSI_Main].[dbo].aspnet_Membership mem
                                           ON us.userid = mem.userid
                                   INNER JOIN [TSI_Main].[dbo].AdminGroupUsers agu
                                           ON mem.userid = agu.userid
                                   INNER JOIN [TSI_Main].[dbo].AdminGroups ag
                                           ON agu.[adminGroup] = ag.id
                            WHERE  ag.[deleted] = 0)
```

but with regards to your question moving gu to a CTE puts it in scope.

```
WITH gu
     AS (SELECT agu.userid,
                us.id
         FROM   [TSI_Main].[dbo].aspnet_Users us
                INNER JOIN [TSI_Main].[dbo].aspnet_Membership mem
                        ON us.userid = mem.userid
                INNER JOIN [TSI_Main].[dbo].AdminGroupUsers agu
                        ON mem.userid = agu.userid
                INNER JOIN [TSI_Main].[dbo].AdminGroups ag
                        ON agu.[adminGroup] = ag.id
         WHERE  ag.[deleted] = 0
         GROUP  BY agu.userid,
                   us.id)
UPDATE anno 
SET    [usercreated_id] = CASE
                            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id
                                         FROM   gu
                                         WHERE  anno.[usercreated_id] = gu.id) THEN 'SOMEVALUE'
                            ELSE [usercreated_id]
                          END
FROM   [Case_11268].[dbo].[Annotations] anno
```

A derived table can only be selected `FROM` when the derived table immediately precedes the alias. So you would need to move the whole definition to use the derived table there.

```
UPDATE anno 
SET    [usercreated_id] = CASE
                            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id
                                         FROM   (SELECT agu.userid,
                                                        us.id
                                                 FROM   [TSI_Main].[dbo].aspnet_Users us
                                                        INNER JOIN [TSI_Main].[dbo].aspnet_Membership mem
                                                                ON us.userid = mem.userid
                                                        INNER JOIN [TSI_Main].[dbo].AdminGroupUsers agu
                                                                ON mem.userid = agu.userid
                                                        INNER JOIN [TSI_Main].[dbo].AdminGroups ag
                                                                ON agu.[adminGroup] = ag.id
                                                 WHERE  ag.[deleted] = 0
                                                 GROUP  BY agu.userid,
                                                           us.id) AS gu
                                         WHERE  anno.[usercreated_id] = gu.id) THEN 'SOMEVALUE'
                            ELSE [usercreated_id]
                          END
FROM   [Case_11268].[dbo].[Annotations] anno
```

Comment: This looks fantastic. However, I'm getting:
`Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateAnnotations, Line 10`
`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: @seebiscuit - Can't see anything in the code that would cause that. Triggers on the table?

Comment: Please see the edit. That may be the cause?
I can't get over by how good your Answer looks :) Very rich!

Comment: There was a trigger! That was it!